# Will Lithium displace a sodium salt?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, alkali-metals

This question is based on a discrepancy I have observed in my limited knowledge about the reactivity and electrochemical series.
In the reactivity series it is mentioned that Na>Li in reactivity which is understandable considering the higher ionization energy of Li. This property is shown in various situations such as the more vigorous reaction of Na with water.
On the other hand, in the electrochemical series, Li is given as a stronger reducing agent than Na.

So, my question is whether Li will displace an aqueous solution of a sodium salt, for example, sodium sulphate to form lithium sulphate(typically the outcomes of these displacement reactions are explained on the basis of the reactivity series, not the electrochemical series-at least at my level). Also, will Li displace sodium oxide?

If so, is the higher value of Na in the reactivity series just an indication of the *rate of the reaction* as opposed to the outcome of the reaction?

Comment: Sodium reacts and releases energy faster, lithium releases more energy (in water environment). As the higher released hydration energy of lithium gets the upper hand over higher consumed ionization energy. Lithium will not displace sodium in water solutions, but hydrogen.

Comment: @Poutnik Please could you elaborate.

Comment: Reactivity serie is matter of kinetics, electrochemical serie is matter of thermodynamics.

Comment: On the other hand, I would be pleased to simply know how the redox potentials of alcaline metals have been practically measured. Because they cannot be determined in water, because in electrolysis, water is reduced at the cathode before $\ce{Na^+}$ or $\ce{Li^+}$ . Does anybody which solvant or which technique was used to get $\ce{Li^+}$ at $-3.04$V ?

Comment: @Poutnik Then why doesn't lithium displace sodium in an aqueous of sodium sulphate(as per your comment)? How is that linked to kinetics?

Comment: Think longer. This is linked to thermodynamics. What are standard redox potentials of Lithium, sodium and hydrogen?

Comment: @Poutnik Yes, wouldn't Lithium sulphate be thermodynamically more stable considering the high hydration energy released? So, shoudn't Li displace sodium to form the more thermodynamically stable product?

Comment: Hydrogen + lithium hydroxide are thermodynamically much more preferred to lithium sulphate + sodium.

Comment: @Poutnik Ok, understood. One final question-Does the greater reducing power of Li compared to Na influence the outcome of any reaction and is there any chemical application/observation to this? If not, can I safely ignore the higher reducing power of Li when dealing with inorganic reaction prediction and work solely on the reactivity series?

Comment: @Poutnik Also, if I replace the situation with Li(s) added to molten Na2SO4(l) (not aqueous), will Li now displace sodium?

Comment: Consider, in solution, all those alkali metals are *not* bound, but are *ions*.